# Make Column value as key using JSON function in Postgres

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I'm using Postgres database and have a table as below

```
Table Name: Test

id    firstname    lastname
 1     Sam          Crews
 2     John         Dave
```

I'm trying to get result set back in below JSON format but with no luck

Expected:

```
[{"1": {"firstname": "Sam", "lastname": "Crews"}},
 {"2": {"firstname": "John", "lastname": "Dave"}}
]
```

I tried using *row_to_json*, *json_build_object* functions but the output is bit different (as below).

Actual:

```
[{"id": "1", "firstname": "Sam", "lastname": "Crews"},
 {"id": "2", "firstname": "John", "lastname": "Dave"}
]
```

Any pointers on how to achieve expected result would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

`row_to_json()` will always use all column names to create the keys in the JSON document. If you only want two columns, you need to explicitly specify them.

You also want a nested JSON object, so you need to nest the methods to create one:

```
select json_agg(json_build_object(
                 id, 
                 json_build_object('firstname', firstname, 'lastname', lastname))
                )
from the_table;
```

Klin made me realize that with Postgres 9.6 you can simplify the creation of the firstname/lastname object:

```
select json_agg(json_build_object(id, to_jsonb(the_table) - 'id'))
from the_table;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
with my_table(id, firstname, lastname) as (
values
(1, 'Sam', 'Crews'),
(2, 'John', 'Dave')
)

select jsonb_agg(obj)
from my_table,
jsonb_build_object(id, to_jsonb(my_table)- 'id') obj

                                              jsonb_agg                                               
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [{"1": {"lastname": "Crews", "firstname": "Sam"}}, {"2": {"lastname": "Dave", "firstname": "John"}}]
(1 row)
```